# Laravel 10 / Inertia / Vue3 (All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response)

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have developed an application using laravel 10, inertia and vue3.
Everything works fine locally. I have just uploaded the application to the server, but the links do not work. Let me explain in more detail. If I click on any link, this error message appears:

**All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received.**

Below I show the code used to create the links on the vue components and how the backend interacts. In this example I show how I access an individual page of each product.

**Vue component**

```
<script setup>
import {Link} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
</script>

...in template

 <h3 class="product-title"> <Link :href="`/products/${product?.slug}`">{{ product?.title }}</Link> </h3>
```

**Laravel**

```
    public function show($ref)
    {
 
        $product = new ProductResource(Product::where('ref',$ref)->first());
        return inertia('Admin/Products/Show', ['product'=> $product ]);
    }
```

If I access any link by simply including the link, it works. The problem appears when I click on any link.

If I copy and pase any link like this it works.

https://ecommerce.deniswebapp.ch/products/dresses-long-winter-black-35

I am including the link to the application so you can test it yourself.
This is my first project with Inertia and I cannot understand what the problem might be.

This is the projec [link](https://ecommerce.deniswebapp.ch/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from the server doesn't include the [`X-Inertia` header](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/blob/v0.6.11/src/Response.php#L107) which is necessary for a valid [Inertia response](https://inertiajs.com/events#invalid).

The `Headers` in the response to the XHR request performed when the link is clicked are:

```
Content-Encoding:
br
Content-Type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:
Tue, 09 Jan 2024 13:48:17 GMT
Server:
nginx
Vary:
Accept-Encoding
```

Since the JSON response contains the page object, we can infer that the `X-Inertia` response header is dropped by Nginx.

I recommend explicitly configuring your server to [include the `X-Inertia` header in the response](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header) from the proxy.

```
proxy_pass_header X-Inertia;
```

Comment: I had the chance to add what you suggested, but the problem persists. I think the problem may be the csfr tokens. Error 419 always appears

Comment: @Daniel, that's interesting. I didn't get a 419 when I tested the links. 
Are you able to debug if the response from the proxy server has the `X-Inertia` header?

Comment: Hi, yes I could debug: here the result:
Content-Encoding:
br

Content-Type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:
Wed, 10 Jan 2024 09:43:50 GMT
Proxy_pass_header:
X-Inertia;
Server:
nginx
Vary:
Accept-Encoding

I put your suggestion as following in the server: proxy_pass_header: X-Inertia

But still the same problem.

Comment: @Daniel The header in the request doesn't look right. I'm seeing `proxy_pass_header: X-Inertia` in the response headers. Did you write this directive in the nginx configuration?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in the nginx configuration. But I have no experience, so I don't know if I entered it correctly. What was done wrong?

Comment: I rewrote in the nginx config. I wrote X-Intertia:true and now it's working. You have solved a huge problem for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Super! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is another problem as I told you. All post,get and put requests return error 419.

Comment: Here is the post in case you maybe have an idea how to solve it..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795757/laravel-10-inertia-vue3-in-production-error-419?noredirect=1#comment137147097_77795757